# jQuery Validator no formatting messages

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, metadata

I have translated the messages I desire using the method I always use. The message comes up just fine, the problem is the number is missing.

My code for message translations:

```
$.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
            required: 'Este campo es requerido.',
            maxlength: $.validator.format("Favor de ingresar no mas de {0} caracteres."),
            max: $.validator.format("Favor de ingresar un valor menos de o igual a {0}."),
        });
```

This is the output:

[image]

It validates just fine, if I lower the values under 100 it accepts them. So it means the rules in place are fine but the messages aren't being formatted.

[image]

**UPDATE**

On line 217 of `jquery.validate.js` I placed a `console.log` of the replace method:

```
$.validator.format = function( source, params ) {
    if ( arguments.length === 1 ) {
        return function() {
            var args = $.makeArray( arguments );
            args.unshift( source );
            return $.validator.format.apply( this, args );
        };
    }
    if ( arguments.length > 2 && params.constructor !== Array  ) {
        params = $.makeArray( arguments ).slice( 1 );
    }
    if ( params.constructor !== Array ) {
        params = [ params ];
    }
    $.each( params, function( i, n ) {
        console.log(source.replace( new RegExp( "\\{" + i + "\\}", "g" ), function() {
            return n;
        }));
        source = source.replace( new RegExp( "\\{" + i + "\\}", "g" ), function() {
            return n;
        });
    });
    return source;
};
```

Unfortunately even logging that replace method it comes out with the number `0` still. So it's not getting the actual data that is missing from validator:

[image]

Comment: It works correctly for me: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/rsoojtcp/

Comment: What version of jquery-validate are you using? In 1.12, `data-rule-max` changed to `data-ruleMax`.

Comment: It looks like you're using another plugin to change the inputs from text fields to combo boxes, maybe that's not compatible with `jquery-validate`.

Comment: Please post a MCVE of the actual code, instead of pictures of your code.  I am referring to your HTML markup.

Comment: No, it's not version nor the spinner element from jquery UI. I've tried it with all my same components that effect that field and my validator 1.13 and it works in fiddle just not my site: http://jsfiddle.net/vkockys1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something that I didn't think of originally in my original post was that I am using smarty templates. And not all of the Javascript I am wrapping in `{literal}` tags. So it was translating the `{0}` in the message array as a smarty variable. So on line 232 of `jquery.validate.js` it wasn't actually replacing anything because the `{}` brackets were missing.

So by wrapping my replacing code inside the `tpl` file with `{literal}` tags it fixed the entire problem.

New code:

```
        {literal}
        $.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
            required: 'Este campo es requerido.',
            maxlength: $.validator.format("Favor de ingresar no mas de {0} caracteres."),
            max: $.validator.format("Favor de ingresar un valor menos de o igual a {0}."),
        });
        {/literal}
```